# Spin of electrons about it's own axis, release of energy & COLLAPSE of atom?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, atoms

An electron spins about it's own axis. So it has rotational accln. Thus, according  to Maxwell's Electromagnetic Theory , Rotational Kinetic energy must be released. Thus, at some pt. of time , shouldn't the energy of an electron become 0 & then shouldn't the electron move out of  the atom, eventually leading to the atom only having the nucleus .

Comment: [The electron isn't spinning on it's own axis](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-spin-as-it-relates-to-subatomic-particles)

Comment: Why aren't you concerned with electron's "rotation" around the nucleus in the first place? (The explanation is pretty much the same: there is no actual rotation.) But wait, there is more to it: a **free** electron has spin as well! Had it lose energy through some mechanism, what would eventually become of it?

Comment: hey @IvanNeretin , I do know about the rotation of electrons around the nucleus(in fact it was a defect of Bohr's Theory). My question's  pretty similar(though it's about rotation of electrons about it's own axis). Hope u get my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing macroscopic spin with the **spin** *angular momentum* of electron here. Electron is a point entity and does not posses a macroscopic spin (i.e. it does **not** spin on its axis).
 It does have angular momentum which is expressed as '*spin angular momentum*' which is of-course quantized.

This link   by  **John Rennie** will be useful for understanding : [The electron isn't spinning on it's own axis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-spin-as-it-relates-to-subatomic-particles)